# Outlier treatment in Vector Autoregression (VAR) Model using vars package in r

Tags: r, time-series, outliers, autoregressive-models

I have the same problem as the following post, but I have more samples and the index of the outlier is known.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73304/outlier-treatment-in-vector-autoregression-var-model?newreg=31eda9f1618047dcba346fdcb8014dcb

I tried deleting the outliers; it works. I also want to try including dummy variables for the outliers (the dummy take the value of 1 on the outliers, and zero otherwise) and compare the two treatments. One reason I want to do this is that a special event at t1 may also impact the response variable y2 at t2. However, its impact on t2 is not significant enough, thus y2 is not an outlier.

`Question`: The VAR in R package `vars` returns "NAs in y". I guess is because the dummy variable comprises a lot of zeros. I don't know how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your dummy variables only include 0 or 1, and are numeric rather than character?

Comment: @JohnPaul Yes. Not only dummy variables, a missing value or 0 in other numeric predictors would fail the var function most of the time.